# Elasticsearch Cross cluster replication - Follower index "index_not_found_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 elastic clusters (Cluster1 and Cluster2) and I am trying to configure a follower index in Cluster2 from a leader index of Cluster1.

I have followed the next steps:

1. Add Cluster1 as remote cluster in Cluster2.

[Configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3fYP.png)

2. Configure the next users:

- In Cluster1 user "cross-cluster-user" with the role "remote-replication".
  [cross-cluster-user configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yce9W.png)
- In Cluster2 user "cross-cluster-user" with the role "remote-replication".
  [cross-cluster-user configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylQNh.png)

3. When I try to create a follower index of "newblogs" index, I have the next error:

> Can't create follower index no such index [newblogs]
> index_not_found_exception: no such index [newblogs]

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSc0b.png)

The newblogs index exists in Cluster1:
[Get index result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8ujV.png)

My elasticsearch version is 8.3.3.

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards.

elasticsearch.yml (Cluster1)

```yaml
cluster.name: elastic-lab
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
network.host: _eth1_
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node1"]

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 28-08-2022 15:46:47
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

elasticsearch.yml  (Cluster2)

```yaml
cluster.name: elastic-lab2
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
network.host: _eth1_
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node1"]

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 28-08-2022 16:07:28
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

Comment: Can you confirm that all prerequisites are fulfilled: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ccr-getting-started-tutorial.html#ccr-getting-started-prerequisites, Also you seem to be [missing some privileges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ccr-getting-started-tutorial.html#_local_cluster_4) on Cluster2

Comment: Thanks, I have correct Cluster2 role permissions (I updated the image) and I confirm that all prerequisites are fulfilled:
- The user I use has the role of superadmin.
- The trial license is active since yesterday on both clusters.
- In both clusters there is only one elasticsearch node and in the configuration it is not specified that they have any role (so they should have all of them).

The error persists :(

Comment: 1) Can you share the full stack trace you can get from the ES server logs? 2) Are you sure that your [deployments trust each other](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-trust-management.html)? 3) Did you create the [cross-cluster user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ccr-getting-started-tutorial.html#_local_cluster_4) with the remote-replication role?

Comment: Hi Val,
1) No log is generated in Kibana or ES when I try to create a follower index. I add the ES configuration of the clusters in case it is useful.
2) I think that cross-cluster trus configuration applies only to ECE deployments, however, my architecture is on-promise VM, right?

thanks!

Comment: Could it be a license issue ? If I remember correctly it might necessitate a licence to do that. [Elastic features per licenses](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)

Comment: Hi Paulo, I have a trial license in both clusters until September 27, so that should not be the problem. Thank you also for your reply.

Comment: What about my 3rd question?

Answer (score 1):

It was a very silly problem...I have 2 Clusters (Cluster1 and Cluster2) and each consists in 1 elasticsearch node (hostname: node1) and 1 kibana virtual machine (hostname: node4). "Node1" has different IP addresses in each cluster, but when I configured node1 (of Cluster1) as a seed node, the resolution of the name "node1" was the IP address of the node1 from Cluster2. This was the reason the remote cluster appeared as connected, it was connected to its own node1!

I have configured the seed node by IP (instead of hostname) and it seems to work! I had to change the option "verification_mode" in elasticsearch.yml of all nodes to the value "none" (because I was having SSL issues and this is only a lab).

Note: I didn´t have to configure any user or role for the clusters to connect, even though the documentation says so.

Best regards.

Comment: Finally a solution! Name resolution was also my problem, thanks